# Log4j2 JSON layout: handling of "\n" (new line character)

Tags: java, json, log4j2

I'm using Log4j2 and its `JSONLayout` to produce logs in JSON format.
Everything works fine but when I use `Logger.warn(String message, Throwable t)` like:

```
l4j2Logger.warn("log1...\n...log2", new Exception("ex1...\n...ex2"));
```

I get in my logs:

```
"message":"log1...\n...log2",
"throwable":"java.lang.Exception: ex1...\\n...ex2\\n\tat test.Test.log(Test.java:73)\\n\tat......"
```

In the `message` key, the `\n` character is written `\n` in the log file,
but in the `throwable` key, the `\n` character is written `\\n` in the log file.

As I need to parse these logs, the JSON parser doesn't like `\\n`, which seems normal since the [JSON specifications](http://www.json.org) indicates that `\n` shall be used.

Here is an extract of my log4j XML configuration file:

```
<Appenders>
    <File name="FileAppender" fileName="log4j2.log" append="true">
        <JSONLayout complete="true" compact="false"/>
    </File>
</Appenders>
```

Do you know why Log4j2 is using `\\n` in `throwable`, and if/how I can change that? (I'm using Log4j-2.0-RC1, the latest at this time)

Answer (score -1):

First, be careful interpreting log files. Whatever prints the log files might insert escape sequences.

While parsing a string in a JSON document, \n will be replaced with a newline character. \n is perfectly legal though: The \ character will be replaced with a single \, and then you just have an ordinary n. So instead of a string with a newline character, you get a string with a backslash character followed by an n character delivered by the parser. The parser shouldn't have any problems with that.

In your l4j2Logger.warn, you use two strings containing newline characters. It seems that in the JSON document, "message" has a string value that represents the first argument. The "throwable" value seems has a string value that represents source code. The line in your log file is:

```
"throwable":"java.lang.Exception: ex1...\\n...ex2\\n\tat test.Test.log(Test.java:73)\\n\tat......"
```

This will be parsed as the string

```
java.lang.Exception: ex1...\n...ex2\n  at test.Test.log(Test.java:73)\n  at......"
```

I'd check what tools read these log files; this seems to be intended.

Comment: Indeed, `\\n` is parsed as `\n`: this is a nominal behavior for JSON parser. But the point is WHY log4j2 uses `\\n` instead of `\n` like it does for `message` field? The expected log file should produce a new line character for both `message` and `throwable` fields... Else, the stack trace in `throwable` is completely unreadable

Comment: I tried to parse this with http://www.json.org/java/index.html and new lines are printed in `message` field but not in `throwable` field (only `\n` string)